# There is a very slight error in my code. What could it be?

Tags: sas

The objective of my code is to display the type, number of distinct values, and the number of missing values. And at this point, I'm very close to getting it. In my *smmry* table, you can see the number of missing values for all the variables. However, by the time I'm done with my left join, the table final_Alpha_ doesn't display the number of missing values for two of the variables and instead just shows ".". What went wrong in the left join? Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
%let set=sashelp.cars;

    proc transpose data=&set(obs=0) out=names;
       var _all_;
       run;
    proc sql;
       select cats('_',_name_,'=missing(',_name_,');') into: stmts separated by ' ' from names;
       run;
    
    data missing;
       set &set;
       &stmts;
       keep _:;
       run;
    proc summary data=missing;
       var _numeric_;
       output out=smry sum=;
       run;
    proc transpose data=smry(drop=_type_ _freq_) out=smry_;
       run;

data _smry_(drop =  _name_);
set smry_;
name=compress(_name_, , 'kas');
run;

proc sort data=_smry_;
    by name;
run;

proc contents data=&set out=con_(rename=(name=TableVar));
run;

proc freq nlevels data = &set;
ods output nlevels=distinct;
run;

proc sort data=distinct;
    by TableVar;
run;
data _smmry_(rename=(name= TableVar col1 = miss));
retain name col1;set _smry_;run;

data final_Alpha (keep=TableVar distinct_ TYPE );
    merge distinct(rename=(Nlevels=distinct_)) con_(keep=TableVar type) ;
    by TableVar;
run;

proc sql;
create table final_Alpha_ as select * from final_Alpha as x
left join  _smmry_ as y
ON x.TableVar=y.TableVar;quit;

proc sort data=final_Alpha_ out=_final_Alpha;
by descending miss;
run;

proc freq nlevels data=&set;
tables _all_;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you remove the underscore from the *name* variable and create the name variable. You remove all underscores (not jsut the first one). Therefore, _MPG_City becomes MPGCity. Try something like below. The rest of your code seems fine.

```
data _smry_(drop =  _name_);
set smry_;
name = substr(_name_, 2);
run;
```